# How to change the root directory of this JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am trying using [this piece of code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/DisplayafilesysteminaJTreeview.htm) since it is simpler than other solutions for showing files and folders in a JTree.

The only problem is that I do not know how to give it a root directory. It has a default path, which I cannot identify it.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;

/**
 * Display a file system in a JTree view
 * 
 * @version $Id: FileTree.java,v 1.9 2004/02/23 03:39:22 ian Exp $
 * @author Ian Darwin
 */
public class FileTree extends JPanel {
  /** Construct a FileTree */
  public FileTree(File dir) {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    // Make a tree list with all the nodes, and make it a JTree
    JTree tree = new JTree(addNodes(null, dir));

    // Add a listener
    tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
      public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e
            .getPath().getLastPathComponent();
        System.out.println("You selected " + node);
      }
    });

    // Lastly, put the JTree into a JScrollPane.
    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollpane.getViewport().add(tree);
    add(BorderLayout.CENTER, scrollpane);
  }

  /** Add nodes from under "dir" into curTop. Highly recursive. */
  DefaultMutableTreeNode addNodes(DefaultMutableTreeNode curTop, File dir) {
    String curPath = dir.getPath();
    DefaultMutableTreeNode curDir = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(curPath);
    if (curTop != null) { // should only be null at root
      curTop.add(curDir);
    }
    Vector ol = new Vector();
    String[] tmp = dir.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++)
      ol.addElement(tmp[i]);
    Collections.sort(ol, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    File f;
    Vector files = new Vector();
    // Make two passes, one for Dirs and one for Files. This is #1.
    for (int i = 0; i < ol.size(); i++) {
      String thisObject = (String) ol.elementAt(i);
      String newPath;
      if (curPath.equals("."))
        newPath = thisObject;
      else
        newPath = curPath + File.separator + thisObject;
      if ((f = new File(newPath)).isDirectory())
        addNodes(curDir, f);
      else
        files.addElement(thisObject);
    }
    // Pass two: for files.
    for (int fnum = 0; fnum < files.size(); fnum++)
      curDir.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(files.elementAt(fnum)));
    return curDir;
  }

  public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
    return new Dimension(200, 400);
  }

  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(200, 400);
  }

  /** Main: make a Frame, add a FileTree */
  public static void main(String[] av) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("FileTree");
    frame.setForeground(Color.black);
    frame.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    Container cp = frame.getContentPane();

    if (av.length == 0) {
      cp.add(new FileTree(new File(".")));
    } else {
      cp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cp, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
      for (int i = 0; i < av.length; i++)
        cp.add(new FileTree(new File(av[i])));
    }

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
}
```

Any idea to change the directory path ?

Comment: You pass the input directory as a parameter.  You can pass more than one input directory in as parameters, but the layout is a bit off for more than one input directory.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc So can't I have a variable like `String dir = "C://"` in this code?

Comment: You asked how to change the directory path.  I told you.  If you want to put a directory in the code, change the main method.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Aren't these questions both the same thing? Basically I need to know how to give a path to this JTree. :)

Comment: See also the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the piece of code which is make decisions about what to display.  Basically it's checking to see if you provide any command line parameters and if you, do, it uses those as the root for the `JTree`, otherwise it uses the current working directory (`.`)

```
if (av.length == 0) {
  cp.add(new FileTree(new File(".")));
} else {
  cp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cp, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
  for (int i = 0; i < av.length; i++)
    cp.add(new FileTree(new File(av[i])));
}
```

The `FileTree` itself allows you to specify and path in the form of a `File` object.  You can simply pass what ever path to it via the `FileTree` constructor

Answer (score 1):

I think you are almost there, just a small change,

```
String curPath = dir.getPath();
DefaultMutableTreeNode  fileRoot  = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(curPath);
JTree tree = new JTree(fileRoot);
addNodes(fileroot, dir);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cp.add(new FileTree(new File("D:\\Temp")));
```

This part of code can get any root and JTree lists is sub files. However it does not work with `D:\\`